# How can I write code using this key in javascript to extract the value?

Tags: javascript, html, api, key

This is the `data` I fetch through an API:

```
{ "0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756": { "usd": 0.11039 }}
```

but when I try to access the data to put in html using:

```
var price = data.0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756.usd;
```

The error reads back:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I think it is bc it doesn't identify  `0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756`
as a string but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You can use `data["0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756"].usd;` instead, however it's probably not a good idea to be hard coding such strange keys in your code, perhaps you want to loop over the data such as with a `for in ...` loop.

Comment: Thank you! & thx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
var price = data["0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756"].usd;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the JavaScript MDN Documentation for [Objects and Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

> "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or
> anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty
> string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript
> identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen,
> or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square
> bracket notation."

Your key '**0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756**' is an invalid identifier because it starts with a number. You can access it using square bracket notation:

```
var price = data["0x5af2be193a6abca9c8817001f45744777db30756"].usd;
```